# Clear the feed cache in Opera

Tags: opera, cache, feed-reader

How can I configure Opera to purge read feeds?

I registered a couple of often-updating feeds in Opera and would like to save disk space by having the browser clear out the cache.

Comment: What feed cache are you talking about? Are you just talking about fetched feed messages? If you want to clean them up, delete them and empty trash or shift+del to do it in one shot? Or, are you talking about browser cache files that build up when you view feed messages? If so, it's not separate from the regular browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do it that is built into Opera. It is a frequently requested feature from the looks of it, but per-feed auto-purge is not in Opera at all.

Comment: I thought it could be done by a mail filter, since feeds are managed as mails in Opera, but there is no "rule" for "already read" or even for date.